# Delphi Access Violation Setting IXMLNode

Tags: xml, delphi, access-violation

In the following contrived code snippet I get an access violation on the line marked //***

```
procedure TWizardForm.MakeChanges;
var
  XmlNodeNamedList: IXmlNode;
  someInt: Integer;
begin
  someInt := retrieveInteger();
  XmlNodeNamedList := IXmlNode(someInt); // ***
end;
```

This is very old code that I have inherited, that has been patched to "make it work" at some point.  Any ideas why I would be getting an access violation?

Comment: Why would you expect the code to do anything useful?

Comment: What does `retrieveInteger` do? Why would you fail to include that information? It's clearly relevant, as it produces the value that the code then tries to typecast.

Answer (score 3):

An interface, like `IXMLNode`, is represented in Delphi as a pointer to a list of functions (a vtable in a object instance of a class that implements the interface). An integer is not an interface. By type casting, you are telling the compiler that the integer represents an interface pointer, which it is not, but the compiler believes you. When the program attempts to use this supposed "interface," it fails because the functions it expects to find at the "address" specified by that integer aren't present. The integer doesn't really point at an interface data structure. Any number of bad things can happen when memory isn't laid out as expected; an access violation is the best thing you can hope for. (Worse is if it didn't crash, but instead silently corrupted your application's data.)

Perhaps the original code was supposed to create a new XML node with a textual representation of the integer as the node's value. If that was the goal, you have more code to write.